# Understanding twisted installation in Linux Mint

Tags: python, linux, twisted, sudo

I wanted to install twisted on my Mint Linux 17 machine. I downloaded the source file (from [here](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/T/Twisted/Twisted-14.0.2.tar.bz2)). I extracted the contents into a folder, changed to that folder and ran the following commands to install the library.

```
$ python setup.py build
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

I had to use sudo for the second command, because I could not get it to work without sudo.

Everything was installed without any problem, but when I try to run a sample code I got a import error.

```
$ python datagram.py                  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datagram.py", line 3, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
ImportError: No module named twisted.internet.protocol
```

But it works when I run the same with sudo.

```
$ sudo python datagram.py
```

Why is this happening? What do I need to fix to get twisted programs running without the need for sudo?

Comment: does `which python` and `sudo which python` differ? You should opt for `virtualenv`, that would solve your problem for good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo setup.py install` is one of the ways to screw up your installation of Python and its libraries.  Other members of the club include `sudo easy_install <package>` and `sudo pip install <package>`.

If you want to do a system-wide installation of a Python library (or any piece of software, probably): **use your system package manager**.

If you want to install a version of a Python library different from the version available from your system package manager, use [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org) and install the library into that.

Comment: +1 for this concise explanation of what happened and how to prevent it in future. Where to go to figure out how to fix it after the mistake has already been made though?

Comment: Unfortunately there are many different ways it can be broken.  The way to fix it depends on exactly what happened during the install (which depends on what package is being installed), on the Python version, on the OS, and maybe other factors.  "Delete the entire system packaged Python installation and re-install Python using the system package manager" might be as close to a general answer as there is.